# CSS input styles

Tags: css, forms

I have this input text and an input button...I am looking to have them attach

you can see an example of this at http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/ at the top right corner,

as you can see there is a space between the input text and the input button....how do I get

them to attach?

```
<form class="product_search" method="GET" action="<?php echo $pp_url?>/" >
<input name="product_search" id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" class="wpsc_product_search wpsc_live_search_embed .wpsc_live_search" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="searchBtn" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time :)

- J

Also how do I get the height of the button to be the same height as the input text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this to your form:

```
.product_search{
   font-size:0px;
}
```

or put `input` elements in same line one after other:

```
<input name="product_search" .... /><input type="submit" ...
```

Comment: my next question is....if u look at it on the top right at http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/ how do i get the button and the input text in the same height?

Comment: +1 @user1193385 You have declared decimal pixel height for your `.searchBtn` - that doesn't make sense since `1px` is the smallest screen unit

Comment: @user1193385 For 'next question', it would be better to create new question in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.searchBtn{
 padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: padding is the **inner** distance between the content and the element borders, so it won't affect anything outside it

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
input[type=submit]
{
    margin-left:-6px;
}​
```

also, see this in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Msq7y/